# Mac OS configure syslog send logs to remote rsyslog server encrypted (TLS/SSL)

Tags: macos, logs, ssl

Can MacOS syslog, send logs to remote rsyslog server using TLS/SSL ?

Comment: Yes same as any other syslog - however the main logging in macOS is not via syslog.